# filezilla open with a certain local directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, filezilla

Helo,

i am building a bash script that will open filezilla. I managed to make it to open a certain FTP, but cant figure out how to make it to open a certain local directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by writing the filezilla config file that contains the last opened local directory before open it. In ubuntu its located here :

```
~/.filezilla/filezilla.xml
```

the config name is :

```
<Setting name="Last local directory" type="string"> ... </Setting>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- Either, specify a default folder on
  Filezilla site manager and open it
  with `filezilla --site=the_site_name_and_path` (see below),
- Or, open it up directly, using
  something like:

> filezilla
>   ftp://user:password@ftpaddress/path

The tricky bit has to do with the first option (using the site manager). The syntax is not very intuitive. You need to both specify the path to the site name and prefix the whole thing with a 0.

So, a website named "mysite" that you created in the Site Manager under My Sites\Hosting will be called as this:

> filezilla --site="0Hosting/mysite"

You start by typing '0', then introduce the path to the site as seen on the site manager and ignoring the "My Sites" folder, and finish with the site name. You enclose everything under double quotes.

---

As for **Local Paths**...

Unfortunately this is not possible. Filezilla wasn't meant to be used for automated transfers (see [official stance](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9133), last December, 2008. 2nd Reply). Thus command line options are limited to what you can see through `filezilla -h`.

However there's an [old feature request](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2512) on Filezilla Trac's that was deemed an official answer indicating plans to create a command line client sometime after version 3. I do not know if this is being done or not, if it was abandoned or not. I do suggest you try the filezilla official forums. My guess is due to lack of requests, the idea was dropped.

Comment: my problem is not to open a certain FTP .. but to open a certain local directory ( the left tab ) ... and i know you could put a certain local directory for the ftp server but that would be to much trouble .. i was wondering if there is a way to open directly a certain directory .. as a parameter

Comment: Oh, I see! I'll update my answer to reflect that, for matters of completeness. But for your information. Not, It's not possible.